# USB disabled in BIOS after installing Ubuntu

Tags: usb, usb-installation

I can't boot via USB after installing Ubuntu.

Yes, the BIOS lists USB, but it is disabled.

Yes, USB is at the top of the boot priority in the BIOS, but it is disabled.

Yes, user Da1T, I'm looking in the BIOS.

Burning an image to disc is a waste of time and money.

Comment: What OS are you trying to boot ? EFI ?

Comment: this time was Kali, i had a class and previously installed it and went to reinstall it b/c of a key-server issue, long story, and since fixed it. But I'd installed it, and Ubuntu, with USB. So I'm totally confused why it's as of now on strike. Thx though. :) I'm going to go look into UEFI, but it's an old Dell "Gateway" at least 10-yrs-old, I don't think UEFI was invented yet.

Comment: Reading your previous (all identical) questions, I don't think you have an UEFI system...  If this is the case: have you tried: 1/ upgrading your BIOS to the latest version?  if none is available: 2/ resetting the BIOS to default factory settings?

Comment: Please don't keep asking the same question over and over.

Comment: As @Fabby said: _If_ your BIOS has a problem and for whatever reason disabled USB-boot, you have to try resetting it to factory defaults. Do this by entering the BIOS setup and selecting the "reset"-option. If this is not enough and doesn't change the machine's behaviour, you eventually might have to erase the CMOS memory by disconnecting all power supplies and the little battery on the mainboard. Note that this is dangerous if you don't know what you do. Static electricity can destroy your pc, as well as wrongly assembled cables, jumpers,...

Comment: Last and most advanced and dangerous option is flashing a BIOS update. This does not only reset the CMOS (where BIOS settings are stored), but also rewrites the EEPROM (where the BIOS program code is stored). However, if this fails (power loss while flashing, wrong image,...), your machine will have the same functionality as a toaster, except that it will not automatically throw the bread out when it's done. Don't try this if you don't know what you do. It's your own machine and your own risk...

Comment: @ByteCommander: as long as there is no power cut, flashing BIOS is safe, therefore I always advise to that first as it keeps important settings and do a reset to default factory settings next.  Removing the CMOS battery is impractical for 99% of laptop users...  **;-)**

Comment: @Seth, i was mad, sorry, DA1T gave me the same response twice without reading my question, twice, but your comment is totally helpful.

Comment: Resetting, then if necessary considering flashing. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, if USB is visible in the BIOS, but disabled, there will be a setting elsewhere to 'Enable USB boot' or similar. What the setting is called and where it will be located depends on your motherboard - on mine, it was under 'Security'.

Also, ensure UEFI is OFF, as this can prevent booting from external devices.

Comment: It's. Not. in. the. BIOS. I. have. checked. the. BIOS. 

Methinks an Ubuntu answer I seek, alas all but my decade of computer experience keeps me from the answer. 

Be it something I could solve with terminal, perhaps..............?

Comment: No, the Ubuntu terminal will not help you.  Your problem lies before Ubuntu even boots, so I think it's just a coincidence that this got disabled when you installed Ubuntu

Comment: Bad luck I guess. Thx. :)